# Automated Testing of Nifi flows using Jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, apache-nifi

Is there any way to automatically run regression/functional tests on Nifi flows using Jenkins pipeline ?

Searched for it, without any success.

Thanks for  your help.

Comment: could you provide more information how do you see your test cases? IHMO nifi transforms/transfers data from point A to point B, so you just need to test that data in B corresponds to data in A. No direct connection with nifi.

Comment: Yes, the dataflow very much is as you said. From point A to B, B to C, C to D and so on. Want to create a simple dataflow using Nifi to validate data at each of these points and integrate it with jenkins for automation.

Answer (score 4):

With the recent release of NiFI-1.5.0 and NiFi-Registry-0.1.0, the community has come together to produce a number of SDLC/CICD integration tools to make using things like Jenkins Pipeline easier.

There is both Python ([NiPyAPI](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi)), and Java ([NiFi-Toolkit-CLI](https://github.com/bbende/nifi/tree/nifi-registry-toolkit/nifi-toolkit/nifi-toolkit-cli)) API wrappers being produced by a team of collaborators to allow scripted manipulation of NiFi Flows across different environments. 
Common functions include interaction with integrated version control, import/export of flows as JSON documents, deployment between environments, start/stop of flows, etc.

So, we are working quickly towards supporting things like an integrated wrapper for declarative Jenkins Pipelines, and I would add it is being done fully in public codebase under the Apache license, so we (I am the lead NiPy author) would welcome your collaboration.